# How to prevent swagger from showing allowed methods?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I realized that when I try to access one of the paths defined in my swagger 2.0 with an incorrect method (ie. GET instead of POST), I receive the following message:

> {
>       "message": "Route defined in Swagger specification (/myPath) but there is no defined get operation.",
>       "allowedMethods": [
>           "POST"
>       ]
>   }

The error message is the same described in this post but my question is quite different. [How to get rid of the error in swagger - there is no defined post operation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800314/how-to-get-rid-of-the-error-in-swagger-there-is-no-defined-post-operation)
I don't want that info to be shown even if I'm not calling to the right method.

I've been looking for any kind of configuration that could remove the "allowedMethods" object from the response. I know this is not the end of the world but I would like not to give away any info about which methods are allowed and which aren't. As a plan Z, I've considered defining any other method for every route with an empty response but that seems a bit overkill, don't you think?

Edit: Server is Nodejs.

Comment: What server framework do you use - Java/Springfox, .NET/Swashbuckle, Swagger-PHP, etc.?

Comment: It's nodejs. Added to the original post